# What is the relationship between the domain CONTOSO and the domain east.contoso.com?

Tags: .net, active-directory

This picture shows a domain tree. But how does this relate to the domain on the older NT4-format such as "CONTOSO". If I want to validate a users credentials against the domain and only have it in this format "CONTOSO\username". How do I know what domain (in the picture) this relates to? Or is CONTOSO really a domain-forest?

Also, can I map from a UPN-name suffix domain to a NT4-domain? From user@contoso.com to CONTOSO\user?

I'm working in **C# .NET** so I'd like a solution for this environment...

[image: Domain Tree]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every domain has a NetBIOS name and a DNS name. They don't have to be related (at all), but, they usually are. In your case, the root domain has a DNS name of contoso.com, and more than likely, a NetBIOS name of CONTOSO. The children probably have NetBIOS names of EAST and WEST, but, they could really be anything.

To do what you want (translate the name formats), look at the `DsCrackNames` API. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675970(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would add this as a comment to the previous answer but apparently I don't have enough reputation to do that (what a great rule...).

The previous answer suggested using the DsCrackNames function to convert the names from DNS name to NetBIOS name, but I thought this was not possible because the MSDN documentation for the DS_NAME_FORMAT structure says: 
"DS_DNS_DOMAIN_NAME - Not supported by the Directory Service (DS) APIs".

So how are you meant to specify that you want the domain name to be converted from (or to) DNS format using that function? I'd like to know if anyone has actually successfully got that working, as the way I've always done it is using the DsGetDcName function with the DS_IS_FLAT_NAME flag and the DS_RETURN_DNS_NAME flag (to convert from NetBIOS to DNS, and the other way around for DNS to NetBIOS).

If it helps the OP, here is my API definition for the DsGetDcName API in vb.net (should be easy to convert to c#.net):

```
<DllImport("Netapi32.dll", EntryPoint:="DsGetDcNameW", SetLastError:=True)> _
Friend Shared Function DsGetDcName(<MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPTStr), InAttribute()> ByVal computerName As String, <MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPTStr), InAttribute()> ByVal domainName As String, <InAttribute()> ByVal domainGuid As IntPtr, <MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPTStr), InAttribute()> ByVal siteName As String, <InAttribute()> ByVal flags As Integer, <Out()> ByRef domainControllerInfo As IntPtr) As UInteger
End Function

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Public NotInheritable Class DomainControllerInfo
    Public DomainControllerName As String
    Public DomainControllerAddress As String
    Public DomainControllerAddressType As Integer
    Public DomainGuid As Guid
    Public DomainName As String
    Public DnsForestName As String
    Public Flags As Integer
    Public DcSiteName As String
    Public ClientSiteName As String
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Enum DsGetDcNameFlags As Integer
    DS_FORCE_REDISCOVERY = &H1
    DS_DIRECTORY_SERVICE_REQUIRED = &H10
    DS_DIRECTORY_SERVICE_PREFERRED = &H20
    DS_GC_SERVER_REQUIRED = &H40
    DS_PDC_REQUIRED = &H80
    DS_BACKGROUND_ONLY = &H100
    DS_IP_REQUIRED = &H200
    DS_KDC_REQUIRED = &H400
    DS_TIMESERV_REQUIRED = &H800
    DS_WRITABLE_REQUIRED = &H1000
    DS_GOOD_TIMESERV_PREFERRED = &H2000
    DS_AVOID_SELF = &H4000
    DS_ONLY_LDAP_NEEDED = &H8000
    DS_IS_FLAT_NAME = &H10000
    DS_IS_DNS_NAME = &H20000
    DS_TRY_NEXTCLOSEST_SITE = &H40000
    DS_DIRECTORY_SERVICE_6_REQUIRED = &H80000
    DS_WEB_SERVICE_REQUIRED = &H100000
    DS_RETURN_DNS_NAME = &H40000000
    DS_RETURN_FLAT_NAME = &H80000000
End Enum
```